# Usar JS para aliviar PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Bom, tenho um arquivo PHP que me gera um documento(obtenho por AJAX).
Esse documento passa por algumas funções(que fiz em PHP), como por exemplo, converter uma string para código, somar campos..

Bom, para fins de organização, fiz tudo com PHP esses ajustes(então o documento é entregue pronto, o JS não precisa entrar em cena para finalizar o trabalho após a requisição).

Mas, qual seria a indicação? Aliviar para os servidor(memória, menos processamento, entrega mais rápida.. ??), ou se isso para o servidor seria de tão pouca importância(exige pouco processamento) que não valha apena se prender a detalhes e sim preservar um código mais limpo e mais simples de manutenção.

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta que venho me fazendo, principalmente com *infinite scroll* para fazer o javascript montar os elementos. Mas ter a composição fora da *view* me deixa um pouco incomodado. Aguardo ansioso por um bench sobre o tema.

Comment: Acredito que as respostas estão saindo um pouco do escopo da pergunta que não é quanto a quantidade de requisições, validação antes ou depois, etc... Dando a minha opinião, voltada a pergunta, acredito que o js pode ser, até certo ponto, utilizado como sua view (separada do servidor). Toda a parte lógica e as regras de negócio continuariam no servidor, mas quem processa a parte da interface, quem organiza as informações para exibir ao usuário, seria o js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Ao meu ver, a questão é sobre usar o javascript para fazer o trabalho do PHP. Uma requisição feita com ajax pode retornar dados formatados em `back-end` ou pode receber um `json` e formatar para composição de uma view. *Minha resposta se baseia nessa suposição.*</sub>

Vou dar como exemplo uma requisição simples contendo um array de 2 índices, somente nome e sobrenome e formatos em *JSON*, *XML* e *HTML* para fins de comparação apenas.

---

<sub>**DATA**</sub>

```
 array( array( 'Papa' , 'Charlie' ) , array( 'Papa' , 'Charlie' ) )
```

<sub>**JSON**</sub>

```
LENGTH : 39
STING  : [["Papa","Charlie"],["Papa","Charlie"]]
```

<sub>**XML**</sub>

```
LENGTH : 191
STING  : <usuarios>
             <usuario><name>Papa</name><lastname>Charlie</lastname></usuario>
             <usuario><name>Papa</name><lastname>Charlie</lastname></usuario>
         </usuarios>
```

<sub>**HTML**</sub>

```
LENGTH : 66
STING  : <div>Papa</div><div>Charlie</div><div>Papa</div><div>Charlie</div>
```

---

Um output em **HTML** vai usar o servidor para processar os dados, e você consegue exibir os dados usando funções simples. Pode ser a melhor opção quando se tem pouco fluxo de dados ou para quem não tem tanta familiaridade com javascript. Por outro lado, temos um fluxo maior de dados e pode tornar a aplicação mais presa.

Dados em **JSON** são fáceis de trabalhar com tipo `object`, alem de ter um comprimento bem menor que os outros formatos, e isso é um ponto interessante para economia de banda. **JSON** e **XML** são mais flexíveis e simples de implementar webservices, APPs, desktop, dispositivos móveis...

Não encontrei um benchmark de respeito que pudesse usar como efeito de comparação, mas não vejo uma desvantagem tão grande no tempo de processamento entre PHP e javascript que implique como fator decisivo para mudança. De fato o PHP consome mais recursos para montar o HTML, enquanto o javascript compõe com baixo custo. Mas para responder qual usar ou quando, depende da necessidade - reduzir trafego, flexibilizar a aplicação à outras plataformas... acho que são pontos de maior importância na escolha.

---

<sub>Algumas referencias interessantes</sub>

[<sub>**• Why is it a bad practice to return generated HTML instead of JSON? Or is it?**</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1284381/1244639)

[<sub>• AJAX - Using JSON vs echo HTML</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13354468/1244639)

[<sub>• Why do Facebook, Twitter and GMail render all their data to the browser as JSON as opposed to HTML?</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7341963/1244639)

[<sub>• PHP vs node.js: The REAL statistics</sub>](http://blog.prahladyeri.com/2014/06/php-vs-node-js-real-statistics.html)

[<sub>• The AJAX response: XML, HTML, or JSON?</sub>](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html)

[<sub>• Creating HTML: PHP server-side vs. jQuery clie</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2307535/1244639)

Comment: concordo, depende da necessidade e viabilidade na questão da segurança, não podemos simplesmente dizer que é uma OBRIGAÇÃO validar tudo no server, pois existem vários casos onde pode ser aplicado as "exceções" que resultam em ganho de performance.

Comment: Uau.. Boas referências, quando me sobrar tempo irei analisar estas, obrigado pela resposta, vou considera-la a mais completa e te recompensar. abraços

Answer (score 7):

Olá.

Antes de mais vou começar por citar uma coisinha que as pessoas normalmente dizem ou pensam, quando se deparam perguntas desse tipo:

**Javascript** apesar de ser umas das principais linguagens web, não pode nunca substituir o PHP num aplicativo web que queira manter a integridade total dos dados que saem do cliente para o servidor e vice-versa ( [lê isto](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) se achares que estou errado ).

Outra coisa é, aliviar com o `Javascript`, não é nada mais que pré validar dados antes de serem enviados para o servidor segundo a tua questão.

O `Javascript` em si, serve apenas para lidar com animações e dinamização no lado cliente ou controlar eventos diretamente, sendo que se deixares o `Javascript` fazer a maior parte do serviço, para além daqueles que realmente lhe competem, e depois enviares para o servidor informações e não realizares outra verificação, sabe-se lá quais dados acabaste de enviar diretamente para o servidor, isso porque o `Javascript` fez o trabalho todo incluindo a parte do `PHP` ou outra linguagem `BACKEND` em uso, e o servidor limitou-se a recebe-los como se fosse ele quem os verificou.

Daí ter o princípio de validar com `Javascript` e depois voltar a validar com PHP ou outra linguagem que esteja a atuar no lado servidor. Até os `framework`fazem isso, mas de outra forma.

No final não sei se respondi a tua dúvida, mas espero que entendas ao menos que o `Javascript` não deve nunca substituir o PHP, tenta antes tornar o teu script no lado do servidor mais eficiente.

Comment: exato.. basicamente o mesmo o que respondi

Comment: Sim, é praticamente o mesmo, embora eu tenha estendido a explicação e aprofundando um pouco mais, ainda assim o autor: `As respostas atuais não contêm detalhes suficientes.`, se com isto ele não entender quais são os limites do `Javascript`, então nada posso fazer.

Comment: Pois é.. não entendi o quê mais ele quer.. talvez ele queira ver códigos com casos de estudo comuns e respostas quilométricas com tabelas, gráficos etc.. rsrs

Comment: Sério ? Pensei ter sido o único a achar isso :).

Comment: @Edilson, antes de eu colocar a recompensa de 100, não existia respostas mais completas( ou simplesmente respostas ) que a de DanielOmine, irei analisar estas agora e ver se atendeu a minha expectativa :). Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 4):

As validações devem ser feitas no PHP (server side) independente do que ocorre no lado cliente (js, html).

Para "aliviar" processos, é recomendável aplicar validações em JavaScript para evitar requisições ao servidor.

Exemplos:
Validar formato de email
Validar quantidade de caracteres 
Validar dados somente numéricos ou somente letras

Vale salientar novamente que independente de existir validações no lado cliente, com JavaScript, as mesmas validações devem ser feitas no lado do servidor com PHP.

O "alívio" é útil também pela acessibilidade. Para o usuário no lado cliente, é visualmente melhor e performático.

Comment: Sua ressalva a revalidação seria exclusivamente para caso o browser do cliente não estiver com JavaScript ativado? Mas neste caso não seria melhor verificar a presença deste, e caso não, solicitar na requisição(atraves de um parametro por exemplo) para que fosse feita a validação. Eu sou da ideia de poupar o servidor, são pequenos detalhes mas que somados talvez façam alguma diferença, mas se essa diferença for tão pouca então que valha mais apena garantir aplicação em termos de segurança de dados(como revalidar). Enfim, não sei o tamanho do esforço do servidor para tal feitos.. @Daniel Omine

Comment: Não sei se você entendeu, pois descreveu o mesmo que postei, porém com palavras diferentes. E sobre o caso de browser sem suporte a JS, é irrelevante para o caso. Por isso, nem precisa dizer que precisa ter validação no server e não confiar somente no lado cliente. E novamente salientando, verificação no lado cliente com JS é essencial para evitar processos desnecessários, principalmente requisições ao server. E browser sem suporte a JS, veja bem, sem suporte JS não navegará em praticamente nenhum website. Um request pode ser feito sem browser, por exemplo, mas isso é outro assunto.

Comment: Por qual motivo sua resposta se baseia unicamente em **validação**?

Comment: Entendi que uma forma de "aliviar" seria verificar realmente se a requisição é válida para persistir com o trabalho por parte do servidor, assim não joga uma requisição fora e poupa esforços do servidor. Mas não entendi(talvez por falta de conhecimento) o porquê refazer a mesma(mesma) verificação em ambos(cliente, servidor), se passou em um, o que impede de passar em outro?

Comment: Papa Charlie, não entendi o motivo da sua pergunta. Se puder explicar agradeço.

Comment: Alexandre C. Caus, o motivo é que verificação no lado servidor sempre deve ser feita e a verificação no lado cliente é opcional. Mesmo que faça verificação/validação no lado cliente, as mesmas verificações devem ser feitas no lado servidor pois nem sempre as requisições proveem de um browser convencional.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Se você não tiver validação no servidor, nada impede de que eu faça uma requisição a sua página diretamente, sem utilizar o seu site / formulário, enviando dados inválidos e que possivelmente quebrariam o seu site.

Comment: Porquê tem que repetir a validação do lado do PHP ? Simples, vocês acham mesmo que um método nunca poderia ficar exposto para integração em um webservice ?

Comment: Penso que dizer que é regra, revalidar do lado do servidor, seja errado. Se não comprometer a segurança de um banco de dados não há porquê jogar mais trabalho para o servidor. Não me venha com regras de aplicação, cada caso é um caso.

Comment: Alexandre.. ??? Como assim ?  REalmente não entendo como vc não consegue entender ?? rsrsr.. Tipo assim cara, vc está distorcendo o que foi colocado. Nenhuma das resposta diz que "todo o peso" deve ficar para o server.. de modo algum. Enfim.. aprenda a ler e interpretar..

Comment: @DanielOmine, querendo ou não, isso ficou debaixo dos panos, da para entender que virou regra. Não vou discutir sobre isso, apenas digo que nada é regra, depende de cada caso, sua resposta valeu mas não foi suficiente.. obrigado!

Comment: "debaixo dos panos"?? "virou regra" ?? vc está bem cara ?  rssrs

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: depende muito da sua aplicação e do custo beneficio de trocar a funcionalidade para o front-end.

Usar JavaScript para aliviar o back-end é bom. Mas se você deve usar ou não depende muito da sua aplicação, se você tem uma aplicação que está lenta no back-end, vale a pena deixar mais tarefas para o front-end. Se você tem uma aplicação pequena que está gerando os documentos no back-end sem problemas de performance talvez não seja necessário modifica-la e começar a usar o JS.

Deve-se levar em consideração o trabalho que dará alterar a aplicação e o quanto isso implicará na performance. Se for uma grande modificação, que levará muitas horas de trabalho e que irá remover pouca carga do back-end, então não vale a pena. Ao contrário se a modificação não for tão complexa, mas aliviar bastante o servidor então vale a pena fazer.

Como já foi citado em outras respostas aqui, tarefas como validação de dados devem sempre ser feitas no back-end, podem ser feitas no front-end para dar um feedback mais rápido ao usuário, mas devem ser refeitas no back-end para verificar a integridade dos dados, já que se os dados forem validados somente front-end criaria a possibilidade de um usuário malicioso desativar o JavaScript e fazer um ataque ao site como por exemplo um [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Outro ponto importante é que atualmente cada vez mais são usados serviços de computação na nuvem para hospedagem, esse serviços normalmente cobram por tempo de uso e/ou uso de CPU, então quanto menos processamento for usado, mais econômico fica. Logo, quanto mais funções forem dadas ao front-end e retiradas do back-end mais barato ficará o serviço.

Comment: é o mesmo ponto de vista que o meu

Answer (score 1):

Para jogar lenha na fogueira, posso sim fazer um código "LIMPO" do lado do cliente até chegar no lado do servidor, e continuar programando javascript no lado do servidor basta usar o **nodeJs**.

> https://nodejs.org/

Então a questão de validar do lado do server ou do lado do cliente, vai depender do que esta validando, se for alguma coisa que não vá comprometer a [segurança de um banco de dados](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL), ou deixar um javascript do lado do cliente onde ele posso sobreescrever uma função para mudar alguma coisa nesses casos deixe tudo do lado do servidor.

Mas uma validação do tipo digite seu login que é o email, e uma função que verifica se o email tem um @ no meio da string, nesse caso eu posso tranquilamente jogar isso do lado do cliente.

Comment: NodeJs é um framework :)

Comment: Essa é uma resposta seria ? Sempre devemos validar os dados de origem duvidosa (que sua aplicação não tem controle). Até mesmo um e-mail / senha deveria ser validado, imagine que você tem uma política de senhas, você poderia validar esta politica antes de ir diretamente no banco de dados e ainda aproveitar a mesma regra no seu cadastro de usuários.

Comment: Concordo que se não comprometer a segurança de um banco de dados, jogar o trabalho para o lado do cliente(alguns casos) pouparia o servidor de fazer trabalhos extras(como repetir o mesmo processo). Não entendo porquê a galera insiste em dizer consistentemente(sem exceção) que deve-se se verificar de ambos os lados. Cada caso é um caso, como SneepS disse, e eu concordo,  "Então a questão de validar do lado do server ou do lado do cliente, vai depender do que esta validando, se for alguma coisa que não vá comprometer a segurança de um banco de dados"

Comment: @Edilson completando o NodeJs é um framework sim que fica do lado do servidor, e usa a linguagem javascript ;)

Comment: @wryel acho que você não me entendeu, a validação de um "email" se ele esta dentro do formato nome@dominio eu valido somente com javascript do lado do cliente, se for usado como login, e ele passar errado simplemeste não vai logar, e o script da validação do lado cliente irá avisar que o formato do email esta errado, simples asism.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA não vai logar mesmo, concordo. O que eu estou querendo destacar aqui é um "requisito" do seu software que você só checou na criação do login, mas não está checando no momento do logon. Eu mesmo confesso que já fiz métodos de logons em que não valido formato de e-mail por exemplo como você mesmo justificou, mas não é certo, estamos burlando o requisito do formato do e-mail, neste caso, deveriamos lançar um exceção ou e sair do fluxo principal (neste caso, economizando uma ida ao recurso que valida os dados providos).

Comment: Acho que estou partindo para o offtopic, mas se concentrando na resposta do autor da pergunta, os dados SEMPRE devem ser validados no servidor, e o que for interessante para aumentar a experiencia do usuário, deve ser validado do lado do cliente.

Comment: @wryel conforme citou ["deveriamos lançar um exceção ou e sair do fluxo principal"] nesse caso eu uso o javascript para lançar a exceção, assim nem chega um email sem ser formatado para o server verificar, e ref. a sair do FLUXO PRINCIPAL isso sim o php tratará(caso seja enviado um post para o server de forma maquiavélica) não logando pois o email não formatado não será localizado no SGBD.

Comment: Exato, há pontos para abordar do lado do servidor(como tratar os dados via POST(evitar sql injection)), e outros que no caso se julgue necessário, mas nada mais, código mais limpo e mais útil, enfim.. minha opinião pelo que vejo e consigo analisar dos usuários.. Obrigado pela Resposta SneepS NinjA, nodeJS realmente é interessante, vou ler mais sobre quando sobrar algum tempo!