# Rendenizando HTML com chamada AJAX utilizando PHP e conceito MVC

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mvc

Boa noite.

Normalmente utilizo nos projetos o padrão MVC (Model-View-Controller), independente da linguagem da programação.

No PHP a estrutura dos diretórios fica assim:

```
- assets
    - css
    - js
    - img
    - font
- model
- controller
- view
- session
- database
  index.php
```

A dúvida que tenho é quanto em uma chamada AJAX passando dados para um arquivo PHP e retornando apenas resultados do banco de dados utilizando os parâmetros passados pela chamada AJAX como input.

Seguindo o modelo MVC podemos construir o HTML diretamente no controller ou seria mais certo retornar apenas os valores e fazer com que o HTML seja rendenizado na página utilizando JavaScript porém deixando para o lado do cliente rendenizar o HTML na página o que pode deixar o lado do cliente lento.

Se conhecerem não apenas estas duas soluções, mas sim outras de receber um HTML e rendenizar utilizando o conceito de MVC em uma determinada página também aceito, o que queremos é aprender mais sobre este assunto.

Comment: O *controller* pode usar uma *view* para formatar o HTML, como pode passar os dados tipo JSON para o Javascript renderizar. Mas o *controller* não formata HTML algum, esse é o papel da *view*.

Comment: Sobre deixar `lado do cliente lento`, recomendo essa questão sobre [Usar JS para aliviar PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63115/13412).

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Não foi uma direção como gostaria de dar, ficou um tanto teórico, mas não tinha certeza se sua dúvida é sobre o pattern ou a implementação. Enviar o HTML formatado ou formata-lo com Javascript, acho que esta na questão que citei. Pode detalhar mais sua questão se precisar.